# macOS Terminal ls not listing all files but they are all visible through the Finder

Tags: mac, terminal, finder

I have an external USB drive with about 4TB of files on it. These show up in Finder just fine, but when I use terminal it only shows a single file. Even hidden system directories such as `.Trashes` aren't visible or accessible. I tried different ways of listing files.

[image]

Here is how the disk is formatted:

[image]

I have used Disk Utility to unmount then repair the drive. This took about 4 hours and fixed all the reported problems, and rebooted my Mac. The files seem to work fine through Finder apps.

What could be going on?

Comment: Odd. Is this something that just suddenly happened, or has this always been the case?

Comment: I assume you've ejected the disk and remounted it?  Is there any Seagate SW running that could be making those files appear in the Finder, but keeping them hidden in the Terminal.  You should also type `ls -al` to see hidden/dot files.

Comment: This is something I've noticed lately, hence me trying the disk utility repait. `ls -la` just shows the one file, plus `.` and `..` but none of the macos files that would be there (ds_store, trashes, spotlight and so on). `sudo ls -la` is the same.

Comment: i think @jimtut is onto something. I have an encrypted thunderbolt drive which has stopped asking for the key...
 Finder shows the files anyway, but terminal does not. I have tried all users, and I have tried chown etc